# How do I correctly version a program?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, version

I always see programs that say things like, `Version: 1.5.6`, or something. My question is, how do I properly determine the version?

I'm a C++ programmer, so I would think this is kind of important. I also use Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.

EDIT:
How do I add the version in the code as well?

Comment: There is no right way to version. There are so many ways to do it that it could fill a book.

Comment: [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) is the only specification for versioning I know of and it's pretty good.

Comment: @sftrabbit I like this "standard". I will start using it.

Comment: This _is_ subjective, but it's also very important and there are popular agreements on how to approach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real standard or anything, but this is the general practice:

- The leftmost number represents the "most major" number, meaning it's incremented when the software changes a lot, always upon breaking changes.
- The rightmost number represents the "most minor" number, meaning it's incremented every time the program is released. This is good for changes like bugfixes.
- The numbers in-between simply cover changes of medium importance, e.g. non-breaking, yet large changes like a major bugfix.
- Whenever a number is changed the numbers to the right are reset to 0
- 1.X marks the first usable version, 0.X can be seen as beta/alpha versions

Comment: So, if I were to build a game engine, the version would be 1.0 immediately after the game engine is functional?

Also, how do I set the version in the code and what is an example of a change with a middle number?

Comment: @Tux That is correct. What do you mean set it in the code? Usually you use version control tags.

Comment: Many programs are humble enough to call themselves 0.X for quite some time, despite already being usable.

Comment: @Pubby How would I use version control tags, and can you give me an example of when a middle number is changed?

Comment: @Tux Depends on your VCS, look it up. I updated my post with a better explanation for middle numbers.

Answer (score 1):

normally you place the version in a [VersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) record in the .rc of your project that way the version number will be known by the system e.g. when copying a file.

If you need the version number inside your program as well then the simplest way is to create a header where you have defines with the version number

```
#define VER_FILEVERSION             1,0,0,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "1.0.0.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          1,0,0,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "1.0\0"
```

then include that header in both the .rc file as well as in the file where you need it.